# How to get the total number of Views in a lyout including subviews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-windowmanager

I am trying to count all the views in any layout being displayed to the user. To achieve it, the code posted below was used, but as you see in the layout, it contains

```
    Button
    LinearLayout
        Button
        Button
    TextView
    LinearLayout
```

when the code is executed, it says that the layout has only 4 widgets "Button, LinearLayout, TextView, LinearLayout", while I expected the code to return 6 widgets.
would you please tell me how to get the total widgets contains in a layout including the sub-widgets/views?

**code**:

```
public class ActMain extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = ActMain.class.getSimpleName();
private LinearLayout mMainContainer = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

    this.mMainContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.actMain_mainContainer);
    int totalWidgets = this.mMainContainer.getChildCount();
    Log.d(TAG, "totalWidgets:" + totalWidgets);


    for (int i = 0; i < this.mMainContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = mMainContainer.getChildAt(i);
    }
}
```

}

**layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/actMain_mainContainer"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.alten.test_traversethroughaview_1.ActMain">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/actMain_btn_change"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/decision_change" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actMain_linlay_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/actMain_btn_yes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/decision_yes" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/actMain_btn_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/decision_no" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/actMain_tv_display"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actMain_linlay_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this method:

```
public int getChildrenViews(ViewGroup parent){
    int count = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i=0;i<parent.getChildCount();i++){
        if (parent.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup){
            count+=getChildrenViews((ViewGroup) parent.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

anywhere you want add this part:

```
if (getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() instanceof ViewGroup){
        getChildrenViews((ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView());
    }
```

Comment: thank you for tha answer. but is there another way to main viewGroup/main container that is currently showing on the screen ?

Comment: @LetsamrIt
use this line for access main layout in current screen:
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
 
like below:
`if (getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() instanceof ViewGroup){
            getChildrenViews((ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView());
        }`

I changed main answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only counting its parent child, not all the child in the layout. That means you are counting Grandfather's child not Grandfather's Grandchild. You have to traverse all view to count all child. To do that you can use a recursive function to count all child.

```
getChildCount(View)
  count = 1;
  check the view is instance of ViewGroup
  if it is ViewGroup 
    for each child 
      count+= getChildCount(child)

  return count
```

Call this with root layout

```
totalChild = getChildCount(root)
```

Hope you can count all child this way.

Answer (score 0):

This function will probably help:

```
private int countChild(View view) {
    if (!(view instanceof ViewGroup))
        return 1;

    int counter = 0;

    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

    for (int i=0; i<viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        counter += countChild(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
    }

    return counter;
}
```

It only counts the leaves (ignores the ViewGroups). But if you want to count also them if is straightforward: just substitute `counter = 0` with `counter = 1`.